# How to upgrade pygments.rb use and the latest library of pygments(python)

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using pygments.rb in one of my projects I want to upgrade the python library which is used by pygments.rb to the latest version.

I am using a ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) Python package provides the command line utility `pygmentize` and so does the the [ubuntu package `python-pygments`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-pygments). Pygments is at 1.6 and ubuntu is at 1.4.

If you are currently using the ubuntu package you may want to remove it to avoid any conflicts

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pygments
```

The easiest way to manage Python packages is with [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
```

Then install/upgrade the `Pygments` package

```
sudo pip install Pygments --upgrade
```